# Question about Prism 4

Tags: c#, design-patterns, prism

For example, I made a module for Prism in thise module there are 2 folders Models and Services.
In the folder Models I described the Car class. 
Now I want to create an instance of class Car using the Factory.
Question. How to correctly to do it.

I thought up two variants.

1) Create the new folder Infrastructure and add the class CarFactory.

2) Create a service CarService and use it to create an instance of class Car.

Answer (score 0):

Use the service locator that is also used by Prism. This is usually either Unity or MEF.

Comment: In this scenario, the OP likely needs to pass in parameters to the `Car` class when it is instantiated. If the `Car` class has dependencies as well as needing instance data, it's tough to do with the straight `ServiceLocator` without establishing some sort of "Initialize" pattern. A Factory would not have this limitation. `IUnityContainer` has the ability to pass parameters via `ParameterOverrides`, but passing around a reference to the container is generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the latter approach. This allows us to better isolate our components.  If your ViewModel accepts an ICarService, you can easily mock that, and any dependencies your implementation of ICarService has can be mocked when testing *that*.

This is easy to understand and it's a good place to put more logic than a typical factory would. For instance, we would put methods you'd typically put on a Repository there.  (Save, Get, etc).